# Why am I getting "Declare @Sales_Total

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

I'm getting the error "Must declare @sales_total" when I run this query:

```
--temp Department table needed to handle plywood mills where sawlines are not yet 
DECLARE @Department TABLE
(Department_number uniqueidentifier
,Process_number uniqueidentifier
,Department_Name nvarchar(100))

INSERT @Department 
(Department_number 
,Process_number 
,Department_Name)
((SELECT 'D3BC304C-E3EF-4119-AF9B-02253114B4F2', '87B1D819-06A6-4551-A8AE- 349232F652EC','Elgin.Sawline')  -- Elgin Sawline from Layup
UNION (SELECT '6A5A052C-65B3-4F09-8A85-7E1CD5EF5003', '5CA0310F-D9AA-4E0E-AFAB-DFB77A2A19AD','KF.Sawline')  -- KF Sawline from Layup
UNION (SELECT '81F4E6F2-AC8B-4002-8A40-0D8A632CB041','C86711E2-F86B-4F20-AF44-378791D0369F' ,'MedfordPly.Sawline')  --Medford Sawline from spray line
UNION (SELECT '81F4E6F2-AC8B-4002-8A40-0D8A632CB041','BA420B4D-B413-4F53-A34E-7E1A43B42824' ,'MedfordPly.Sawline')  --Medford Sawline from curtain coater
UNION (SELECT '335465EB-54A1-48E2-A69F-671A38BF7B84','36FD8A9A-0CCE-4B86-972F-F0DD3DF4813D' ,'Oakdale.Sawline') --Oakdale actual sawline
UNION (SELECT '089B086A-E431-4691-B2F0-5F84EBE31F80','86EDB559-4C53-4261-BB32-372677CD4231'              ,'Florien.Sawline') --Florien actual sawline
)
-- temp production table
Declare @Production TABLE
(Plant_Number uniqueidentifier
,Plant_name       nvarchar (50)
,Department_number uniqueidentifier
,Production_Date datetime
,Production_Volume decimal(18,6))

Insert into @Production 
(Plant_Number
,Plant_name
,Department_number
,Production_Date
,Production_Volume)

(
SELECT p.[Plant_Number]
           ,p.plant_name    
  ,d.department_number
  ,pf.date
  ,(ppf.Good_Output/1000)

FROM @Department D
Inner join [TrueOpportunity].[dbo].[Department] dpt
on d.department_number = dpt.department_number

inner join [TrueOpportunity].[dbo].[Plant] p
on p.plant_number = dpt.plant_number

inner join [TrueOpportunity].[dbo].[Process] prc
on d.process_number = prc.process_number

inner join [TrueOpportunity].[dbo].[Production_Fact] pf
on prc.process_number = pf.process_number
--and Month (pf.date) = Month (@monthtodate)

inner join [TrueOpportunity].[dbo].[Production_Process_Fact] ppf
on ppf.production_number = pf.production_number  

--Group by p.Plant_Number, d.Department_number, pf.date, p.plant_name, ppf.Good_Output
)  

Declare @ProdTotal TABLE
(Plant_Number uniqueidentifier
,Plant_name       nvarchar (50)
,Production_Volume decimal(18,6)
,Prod_date datetime)

Insert into @ProdTotal 
(Plant_Number 
,Plant_name 
,Production_Volume
,Prod_date
)


(SELECT   
p.plant_number
,p.plant_name
,sum(p.production_volume) 
,p.production_date
from @Production p
--where plant_name = 'Medford Plywood'
where Production_date between @BeginningDate and @EndingDate

group by p.plant_number
,p.plant_name
,p.production_date)

Declare @Sales TABLE
(Plant_Number uniqueidentifier
,Plant_name       nvarchar (50)
,Actual_Volume decimal(18,6)
,Budget_Volume decimal(18,6)
,Actual_Sales_Dollars decimal(18,6)
,Average_Price decimal(18,6)
,sales_date datetime)

Insert into @Sales 
(Plant_Number 
,Plant_name 
,Actual_Volume
,Budget_Volume
,Actual_Sales_Dollars
,Average_Price
,Sales_Date)

(SELECT   P.[Plant_Number]
          ,pls.plant_code
          ,(pls.[Actual_Volume])  
          ,(pls.[Budget_Volume])
          ,(pls.[Actual_Sales_Dollars])
          ,CASE                    
            WHEN   coalesce (pls.[Actual_Volume],0) = 0 and
                   coalesce (pls.[Actual_Sales_Dollars],0) = 0
                   THEN 0
            ELSE ((pls.[Actual_Sales_Dollars]/pls.[Actual_Volume]))     
            END   AS 'Average Price'
           ,pls.production_date 

FROM woodproduction.dbo.plywood_layup_sales pls
inner join @Production p
on p.plant_number = pls.plant_number
           and p.production_date = pls.production_date

left join woodproduction.dbo.process_inventory pinv
on pinv.plant_code = pls.plant_code
and pinv.inventory_date = pls.production_date

left join trueopportunity.dbo.process prc
on pinv.department_number = prc.department_number




WHERE 
    pls.production_date between @BeginningDate and @EndingDate
    and pls.actual_volume <> 0

GROUP BY
P.[Plant_Number]
,pls.plant_code
,pls.production_date
,pls.[Actual_Volume]  
,pls.[Budget_Volume]
,pls.[Actual_Sales_Dollars]

)
--select * from @Sales

Declare @Sales_TOTAL TABLE
(Plant_Number uniqueidentifier
,Plant_name       nvarchar (50)
,Actual_Volume decimal(18,6)
,Budget_Volume decimal(18,6)
,Actual_Sales_Dollars decimal(18,6)
,Average_Price decimal(18,6)
,sales_date datetime)

Insert into @Sales_TOTAL
(Plant_Number 
,Plant_name 
,Actual_Volume
,Budget_Volume
,Actual_Sales_Dollars
,Average_Price
,sales_date)

(Select
s.Plant_Number 
,s.Plant_name 
,sum(s.Actual_Volume)
,sum(s.Budget_Volume)
,sum(s.Actual_Sales_Dollars)
,CASE                    
WHEN coalesce (sum(s.Actual_Volume),0) = 0 
THEN 0
ELSE (sum(s.Actual_Sales_Dollars)/sum(s.Actual_Volume))     
END                      
AS 'Average Price'
,s.sales_date

 from @Sales s
where s.sales_date between @BeginningDate and @EndingDate

group by s.plant_number, s.plant_name, s.sales_date

)

--Select * from @Sales_Total


Declare @Sales_Prod TABLE
(Plant_Number uniqueidentifier
,Plant_name       nvarchar (50)
,Actual_Volume decimal(18,6)
,Budget_Volume decimal(18,6)
,Actual_Sales_Dollars decimal(18,6)
,Average_Price decimal(18,6)
,Production_Volume decimal(18,6)
,sales_date datetime)

Insert into @Sales_Prod
(Plant_Number 
,Plant_name 
,Actual_Volume
,Budget_Volume
,Actual_Sales_Dollars
,Average_Price
,Production_Volume
,sales_date)

(Select
st.Plant_Number 
,st.Plant_name 
,st.Actual_Volume
,st.Budget_Volume
,st.Actual_Sales_Dollars
,st.Average_Price
,pt.Production_Volume
,st.sales_date

from @Sales_Total st
,@ProdTotal pt
where st.sales_date = pt.prod_date
and st.plant_number = pt.plant_number
and st.sales_date between @BeginningDate and @EndingDate
)

--Select * from @Sales_Prod
```

When I run this query in Management Studio and substitute my date parameters for an actual date, i get the data I am expecting. So I copied/pasted it into SSRS 2008 and then made sure I removed all of my temp dates and replaced them with my 'between @beg..@end' parameter. But for some reason @sales_total is showing up as a 'Define Query Parameters'and I've been looking at it and can't see where, other than DECLARE @Sales_Total TABLE that @sales_total appears by itself as a separate parameter.

Can someone please take a look and see what I'm missing. Maybe I've been staring at it too long? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't `from @Sales_Total st` be `from @Sales_TOTAL st` ?

Comment: In trying to ask the solution, you have exposed the code which you shouldnt be..please hide some code..!!

Comment: @Vijay Still learning how much/little code I need to display. And since I wasn't sure where the error might occur it seemed more prudent to show my whole query rather than be lambasted for showing too little.

Comment: @JimH. somehow I knew it was going to be something simple. THANK!!

Comment: How do I mark this as answered? My other questions had a "check mark" I could select to mark the question as answered. Thanks!

Comment: @JimH. Make that comment an answer so it can be marked as accepted (and so we can upvote it too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's case sensitive... You declared **Sales_TOTAL**, and you tried select from **Sales_Total**.